# JTabbedPane Forced Size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

I have a JFrame that has 3 components on it.

The design is like this:

[image]

My problem happens in the JTabbedPane.

The pane begins off with a settings panel, which is added to it when the whole JFrame loads up. Then, when the user connects, a new tab is added to the pane (the actual chat panel).

When that tab is added to the pane, it overlaps the bottom of the java applet loaded from the local file, which is NOT what I want to do. Here is how it looks:

[image]

As you can tell, the bottom of the highscores and java applet has been cut off. How do I resize the JTabbedPane to make it resize towards the bottom, instead of upwards?

Comment: Layout managers? Mixing heavy and light weight components?

Comment: Yep, it's all in your code, something that you're not showing us.

Comment: Updated appropriately with code.

Comment: you should not edit your original question, this post would never help anyone after reading what you put. edit it or this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Call pack() after adding a tab to the pane.